# Why the initial space of $U$ is $\mathcal M\ $?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> $\textbf {Polar decomposition}$ $:$ Let $\mathcal H$ and $\mathcal K$ be Hilbert spaces. Then any operator $T \in B(\mathcal H, \mathcal K)$ admits a decomposition $T = UA,$ where $U \in B(\mathcal H, \mathcal K)$ is a partial isometry and $A \in B (\mathcal H)$ is a positive operator.

The proof of the above theorem goes as follows $:$

For any $x \in \mathcal H$ we have

$$\left \langle Tx,Tx \right \rangle = \left \langle T^*Tx,x \right \rangle = \left \langle |T|^2 x, x \right \rangle = \left \langle |T|x, |T|x \right \rangle$$ where $|T|^2 = T^*T.$ Thus the map $V_0 : \text {ran} (|T|) \longrightarrow \text {ran} (T)$ defined by $V_0 (|T|x) = Tx, x \in \mathcal H$ is a well-defined isometry and hence it extends to an isometry $U_0 : \overline {\text {ran} (|T|)} \longrightarrow \overline {\text {ran} (T)}$ such that $U_0 |T| = T.$ Let $\mathcal M =  \overline {\text {ran} (|T|)}.$ Let $P$ be the projection onto $\mathcal M.$ Consider the operator $U = U_0 P \in B(\mathcal H,K).$ Then it is easy to see that $UU^*U = U$ and hence $U$ is a partial isometry, where the initial space of $U$ is $\mathcal M$ and the final space of $U$ is $\mathcal N = \overline {\text {ran} (T)}$ and it is easy to see that $U|T| = T.$

Can anybody please make it clear to me as to why the initial space of $U$ is $\mathcal M\ $? The initial space of $U$ has to be ${(\text {ker}\ U)}^{\perp}.$ Since $\mathcal M$ is the projection onto $\mathcal M$ it follows that $\mathcal M^{\perp} \subseteq  \text {ker}\ U.$ Hence $(\text {ker}\ U)^{\perp} \subseteq \mathcal M.$ How to prove the equality here?

Any help in this regard will be warmly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us see that $\ker U\subset\mathcal M^\perp$. Let $x\in\ker U$, $x = u+v$ with $u\in\mathcal M$ and $v\in\mathcal M^\perp$. Then $0 = \|Ux\| = \|Uu\| = \|u\|$, so $u=0$ and thus $x = v\in\mathcal M^\perp$.

Comment: I get it in the following manner $:$ Since $U$ is an isometry on $\mathcal M$ it follows that $\text {ker}\ U = \text {ker}\ P = \mathcal M^{\perp}.$ But then $\text ({\ker}\ U)^{\perp} = \mathcal M^{\perp \perp} = \mathcal {M},$ since $\mathcal {M}$ is a closed subspace of $\mathcal K.$ Done!

Comment: @Anacardium Yes, that's also correct. But too complicated. $U$ is an isometry on $\mathcal M$ and zero on $\mathcal M^\perp$. Done.

Comment: I edited my answer. You can check it as done now. ;-)

Comment: Do you want me to upvote and accept your answer at any cost for the increment of your reputation? ;-)

Comment: An accept would be enough for me. ;-) I don't care so much about my reputation. Just gave away 500 for a bounty. ;-)

Comment:  You are so humourous guy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120547/discussion-between-anacardium-and-amsmath).